# I want jquery draggable script to remembrer position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I allready have this

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>

<body>
<div id="containment-wrapper">
    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content draggable">TEST</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to remember the position of the div when I refresh

Comment: Have you thought about using cookies? Do you want to remember the position by storing the position in a database? It's a very broad and you haven't technically asked a question

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```
var position = localStorage.getItem("pos");

if (position) {
      position = position.split(",");

  $("#draggable").css({ 
      position: "relative", 
      left: Number(position[0]), 
      top: Number(position[1]) 
  });
}

$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
  stop: function(e, obj) {
      localStorage.setItem("pos", obj.offset.left + "," + obj.offset.top);
  }
});
```

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oc1Lxnq7/2/).

[`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) stores the last dragged position in the browser's database. It is persistent for your domain until it is removed/changed. If you want to clear this data after browser's closing, use [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) instead.

However, if you have an user session and you want to store in database for future access, you will have to use form request or better yet, an ajax request to post the element's positions to your server side API, in order to save it in the database and retrieve it for further uses.

Comment: How can I implement that in my code? I made and external .js but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Aghanim just put the whole code inside `$(function() { ... });`